# Procedure or function 'checkClientAccess' expects parameter '@AccessCode', which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures, xmlhttprequest

I've read up on all other posts with the same error and am still having trouble. From what I can tell, I am supplying the parameter, and I use a console log to make sure its not null, but I'm still missing something.

**JavaScript Function (containing XML REQUEST)**

```
 function checkClientAccess()
{
    console.log("step 1: function run");
    var accessCode = document.getElementById('accessCodeInput').value;
    console.log("step 2: get input - " + accessCode );
    
    if(accessCode=='')
    {
        alert("Please enter your access code")
        return false;
    }
    
    var postObj = {
        code: accessCode
    };
    
    var xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("step 3: start xmlrequest");
    xmlRequest.open('POST','https://localhost:44303/api/JSON/checkClientAccess',true);
    console.log("step 4: open post request at specified url");
    xmlRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log("step 5: set request header");
    
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("step 6: waiting for request to be done")
        if(this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200)
        {
            console.log("step 7: request done");
            if(xmlRequest.response=="-1")
            {
                console.log("return value = -1");
                alert("Never make the same mistake twice, you have entered an invalid code");
            }
            if(xmlRequest.response=="1")
            {
                console.log("return value = 1");
                location.href = 'login-page.html?action=valid';
            }
            
        }
    }
        xmlRequest.send(JSON.stringify(postObj));
        
        return false;
        
}
```

**Api Code (ASP.NET MVC)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FelixFringsPharmacopeiaAPI.Models;

namespace FelixFringsPharmacopeiaAPI.Controllers
{

    public class JSONController : ApiController
    {

        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public object checkClientAccess(Models.clientAccess client)
        {
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            string sql = "checkClientAccess";
            var json = ExecuteSPcheckClientAccess(sql, client.accessCode);

            response.Content = new StringContent(json);
            return response;
        }

        
        

        private static string ExecuteSPcheckClientAccess(string queryString, string inputCode)
        {
            string json = "";
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconn"].ToString();

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                // 1.  create a command object identifying the stored procedure
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, conn);

                // 2. set the command object so it knows to execute a stored procedure
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // 3. add parameter to command, which will be passed to the stored procedure
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccessCode", inputCode));
              

                // execute the command
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    // iterate through results, printing each to console
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        json = (string)rdr[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            return json;
        }
    }
}
```

**SQL Server Database Stored Procedure Code**

```
USE [FelixFringsPharmacopeia]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[checkClientAccess]    Script Date: 8/11/2021 10:32:23 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[checkClientAccess]

@AccessCode int
    
AS
BEGIN

if 1 = (select count(*) from AccessCodes where ActiveAccessCode = @AccessCode)
begin
    select 1; --send back success, indicates access code is valid
end

return -1; --send back error, indicates access code is invalid 
    
END
```

Comment: Normally you would include a copy of the output to the console, showing/proving that your console logs actually worked.

Answer (score -1):

> What you are probably needing here is a bit of mentoring and advice to assist with some simple debugging techniques. Simple interactions like this are probably simpler diagnose if you step through the execution line by line with the debugger, at least once so you get a feel for how it works.

You haven't included the `Models.clientAccess` definition but it looks very vanilla, unless you've mapped the properties differently, if you debug into `JSONController.checkClientAccess` you should see that the `client` parameter ihas a value of `null` for `accessCode`.

This is because your `postObj` in the client code is setting a property called 'code'. So unless you tell the API that this should be mapped to `accessCode`, *which can be done*, you will need to change your javascript to this:

```
var postObj = {
    accessCode: accessCode
};
```

When dealing with APIs it can be helpful to use tools like Postman to test your API first, then you can have more confidence when it comes to testing your client-side code.